# Не работают некоторые завтавки Xscreensaver

Tags: linux, archlinux, xorg

Установленная система: ArchLinux

Поставил утилиту xscreensaver. Запускаю xscreensaver-demo. Проблема возникает при выборе некоторых из заставок, например, AntInspect, AntMaze, Atlantiz и многие другие. Они просто не работают.

При запуске утилиты из терминала (а так же при запуске Preview) высвечиваются следующие ошибки:

```
atlantiz: couldn't create GL context for visual 0x24
atlantiz: couldn't create GL context for visual 0x24
xscreensaver: signal: 0: child pid XXXXX (atlantiz) exited abnormally (code 1)
xscreensaver: signal: 1: child pid XXXXX (atlantiz) exited abnormally (code 1)
```

где вместо XXXXX указан номер процесса.

Прошу помощи по решению данной проблемы! Спасибо!